# Maximum Function Count Exceeded

Tags: matlab

trying to use the following code to evaluate a triple integral which is a function of q,u. getting the error,

```
Warning: Maximum function count exceeded; singularity likely. 
In quad at 107
In test1>Inner at 12
In test1>@(x)Inner(x) at 5
In quad at 76
In test1 at 5
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?

```
function [r] = test1(q,u)
b = u;
r = zeros(1);
for i = 1 : length(q);
    r(i) = quad(@(x)Inner(x),-2,q);
end;


function [w] = Inner(k)
w = zeros(1);
for i = 1 : length(k);
    w(i) = quad(@(n)InnerIntegral(n).*unifpdf(k(i)-n,-1,1),0,k(i)-1,k(i)+1);
end;



function [y] = InnerIntegral(n)
y = zeros(1);
for i = 1 : length(n);
    y(i) = quad(@(m)unifpdf(n(i)-m, -b, b).*unifpdf(m,-b,b), n(i)-b,n(i)+b);
end;
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define multiple functions like this, each function's `end` statement must precede the next call to `function`. Currently, it looks like this is one giant function with a subfunction called `Inner` and that subfunction has yet another subfunction called `InnerIntegral`. So `test1` is trying to call `Inner`, but `` `Inner ``'s definition doesn't occur until later *inside of* the definition of `test1`.

Comment: that makes sense, but then in the case how do I pass the variable $b$ among the functions? I didn't want to end them because it seemed that would allow the variable b to be global in scope.

Comment: This is one annoyance of Matlab. One easy fix is to make a second parameter `b` to each of the second two functions, and then change the calls such that you pass `b` to them directly. It is probably also just easier to manage if you save each of these in different .m files, with names that match the function names. Make them take more inputs if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and then I came across a solution which worked or me.

Try using quadgk(Function,lowerlimit,upperlimit) instead of quad(Function,lowerlimit,upperlimit)

hth

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in :

```
function [w] = Inner(k)
w = zeros(1);
for i = 1 : length(k);
    w(i) = quad(@(n)InnerIntegral(n).*unifpdf(k(i)-n,-1,1),0,k(i)-1,k(i)+1);
end
```

the way it's set-up:
w(i) = quad(@(n)fcc(n),0,k(i)-1 , **k(i)+1**);

the last value of quad is set as the tolerance. I think you want to get rid of the 0 term:

```
w(i) = quad(@(n)InnerIntegral(n).*unifpdf(k(i)-n,-1,1),k(i)-1,k(i)+1);
```

Comment: This is a good catch, but is unlikely to cause the error mentioned in the OP. The tolerance won't accept negative values without error, so it's safe to assume here that the mistaken tolerance, `k(i) + 1` would be larger than 1. Thus, it would be a ridiculously lax tolerance and the `quad` function should return crude, inaccurate numbers... but it should *not* cause a maximum function evaluations sort of error.

Comment: while you make a good point about the function call (he is building, calling then destroying anonymous functions...), the problem is in fact related to the tolerance. Try it yourself

Comment: I did try it in Octave. Giving a very large number for tolerance doesn't cause the function to hit max iterations. I could only understand this if you were giving a very small number for tolerance, requiring lots of iterations to try to reach an impossible precision. But that's not the case.

Comment: Here I quote from the [Mathworks documentation for `quad()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html) " Larger values of tol result in fewer function evaluations and faster computation, but less accurate results."

Comment: I think your missing the point: the tolerance parameter can in fact be negative, which will provoke the warning cf. `quad(@(t)t,0,1,-1)` 2)

Comment: When I type this at the prompt, I get: `>>> quad(@(t)t,0,1,-1);
ans =  0.50000` with no warning or error. It appears to just ignore negative tolerances. And certainly doesn't throw any sort of max iteration error.

Comment: I'm running Matlab in Win, as opposed to GNU's Octave, and I get the warning at the command prompt